# Deleting ZooKeeper path with 100,000+ nodes fails with OutOfMemoryError

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a ZooKeeper path with hundreds of thousands of nodes (one parent, 100,000+ children, no further children). If I try to delete it using the CLI and `rmr` command, it waits for about a minute and fails with the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZKUtil.deleteRecursive(ZKUtil.java:50)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:714)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:599)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:362)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:290)
```

Looks like internally, `rmr` is creating a variable containing all the node names, and this variable is exceeding the available memory. Presumably, this needs to be done to ensure that the delete is an atomic operation?

I can raise the memory using `-Xmx` but was wondering if there is a better way. I do not require this to be an atomic operation, but was hoping to avoid writing a script that iterates over each one and removes it individually.

---